# Trying to make my GADT an instance of Num, but having trouble multiplying across constructors

Tags: haskell

Here is my GADT:

```
data Vector v where
    Zero    :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => Vector a
    Scalar  :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => a -> Vector a
    Vector  :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> Vector [a]
    TVector :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> Vector [a]
```

Basically, it is representing a vector containing elements that belong to the type classes Num, Eq, and Show.

I would like Vector itself to be a Num, so I do the following:

```
instance Num (Vector v) where
    (Zero) + (Zero) = Zero
    -- etc
    (Vector a) * (Scalar b) = Vector $ map (* b) a -- This does not work
```

When I run the code, I get:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ [a])
    from the context (v ~ [a], Num a, Eq a, Show a)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Vector :: forall a. (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> Vector [a],
               in an equation for `*'
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, that is, the arguments must be of the same type; but the `Scalar` and `Vector` constructors give you different types. So it would be possible to implement `(*)` for the `Zero` and `Scalar` constructors, and for the `Vector` and `TVector` constructors, but not for combinations thereof.

If you want the `v` parameter of the `Vector` type to denote the element type of the vector, then just change the `Vector` and `TVector` constructors to return `Vector a` instead of `Vector [a]`:

```
data Vector v where
    ...
    Vector  :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> Vector a
    TVector :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> Vector a
```

You can also abbreviate your repeated class constraint with the `ConstraintKinds` extension:

```
type EqNumShow a = (Eq a, Num a, Show a)
```

Presumably with a better name that conveys why you want those particular constraints.

Comment: Which then means it doesn't need to be a GADT, right? Since all the constructors have the same result type anyway.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski: He still wants existential quantification on the `a` for each constructor, and to have `Vector v` denote a vector with elements of type `v`. I don’t think you can do that with just `ExistentialQuantification`. The alternative would be to allow any element type, and impose the class constraints from outside.